# Search and combine text from the same columns related to a specific variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, summarize

i have the following example data frame in R:

```
ID = c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,2),4,5);ID
VAR = c(rep("A",3),"B",rep("C",2),"D",rep("E",2),"F","G");VAR
D = data.frame(ID,VAR);D
```

My purpose is to construct a separate variable outside the data frame that will search all the ids and print the combined texts related to each id.
For example the data frame

| ID | VAR |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | D |
| 3 | E |
| 2 | E |
| 4 | F |
| 5 | G |

ideal output given the above data frame in R will be :

| ID | TEXTS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B |
| 2 | C,D |
| 3 | E |
| 4 | F |
| 5 | G |

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
> aggregate(. ~ ID, unique(D), c)
  ID  VAR
1  1 A, B
2  2 C, D
3  3    E
4  4    F
5  5    G
```

or

```
> aggregate(. ~ ID, unique(D), toString)
  ID  VAR
1  1 A, B
2  2 C, D
3  3    E
4  4    F
5  5    G
```